# Undefined symbol references in boost and CImg

Tags: c++, cimg

I am new to using CImg and boost. I am getting undefined symbol references as mentioned below, in the code also shared below.

I am using this command line to build it: g++ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11 grayscaleConvertor.cpp &> errLog.txt

I am using the -l args in the compiler command. eg: -lboost_filesystem which I read on another post in stackoverflow, but that is not helping resolve the boost::filesystem:: symbols

locate CImg : /usr/include/CImg.h

locate boost: /usr/include/boost (plus more lines)

errLog.txt

> /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function `main':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to`boost::filesystem::path::extension() const'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text+0x213): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text+0x68e): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text+0x698): undefined reference to`boost::system::generic_category()'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text+0x6a2): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::system::error_code::clear()':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_code5clearEv[_ZN5boost6system10error_code5clearEv]+0x10): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::filesystem::path::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) const':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost10filesystem4path7compareERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZNK5boost10filesystem4path7compareERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x3b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::compare(boost::filesystem::path const&) const'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem6existsERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem6existsERKNS0_4pathE]+0x24): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::filesystem::is_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem12is_directoryERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem12is_directoryERKNS0_4pathE]+0x24): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem15is_regular_fileERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem15is_regular_fileERKNS0_4pathE]+0x24): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::filesystem::directory_entry::status(boost::system::error_code&) const':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost10filesystem15directory_entry6statusERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZNK5boost10filesystem15directory_entry6statusERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x31): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::directory_entry::m_get_status(boost::system::error_code*) const'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::filesystem::directory_entry::symlink_status(boost::system::error_code&) const':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost10filesystem15directory_entry14symlink_statusERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZNK5boost10filesystem15directory_entry14symlink_statusERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x31): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::directory_entry::m_get_symlink_status(boost::system::error_code*) const'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp::~dir_itr_imp()':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem6detail11dir_itr_impD2Ev[_ZN5boost10filesystem6detail11dir_itr_impD5Ev]+0x2e): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem18directory_iteratorC2ERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem18directory_iteratorC5ERKNS0_4pathE]+0x4a): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code&)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem18directory_iteratorC2ERKNS0_4pathERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost10filesystem18directory_iteratorC5ERKNS0_4pathERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x4b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::increment()':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem18directory_iterator9incrementEv[_ZN5boost10filesystem18directory_iterator9incrementEv]+0xf): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_increment(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::system::error_code*)'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`cimg_library::cimg::Mutex_info::trylock(unsigned int)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4cimg10Mutex_info7trylockEj[_ZN12cimg_library4cimg10Mutex_info7trylockEj]+0x1c): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`cimg_library::CImgDisplay::screen_width()':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay12screen_widthEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay12screen_widthEv]+0x26): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay12screen_widthEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay12screen_widthEv]+0x96): undefined reference to`XCloseDisplay'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::screen_height()':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13screen_heightEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13screen_heightEv]+0x26): undefined reference to`XOpenDisplay'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13screen_heightEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13screen_heightEv]+0x96): undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_handle_events(_XEvent const*)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0xb5): undefined reference to `XUnmapWindow'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x112): undefined reference to`XCheckWindowEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x1f0): undefined reference to `XResizeWindow'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x2c2): undefined reference to`XCheckWindowEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x317): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x335): undefined reference to`XSync'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x356): undefined reference to `XSetInputFocus'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x472): undefined reference to`XCheckWindowEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x5c4): undefined reference to `XCheckWindowEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x601): undefined reference to`XLookupString'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x635): undefined reference to `XQueryKeymap'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x6d8): undefined reference to`XLookupString'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x71b): undefined reference to `XCheckWindowEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x7f0): undefined reference to`XCheckWindowEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_handle_eventsEPK7_XEvent]+0x861): undefined reference to `XCheckWindowEvent'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_events_thread(void*)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x6a): undefined reference to `XCheckTypedEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x94): undefined reference to`XCheckMaskEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x14c): undefined reference to `pthread_testcancel'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_set_colormap(unsigned long&, unsigned int)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13_set_colormapERmj[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13_set_colormapERmj]+0x2a2): undefined reference to `XStoreColors'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_map_window()':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv]+0x50): undefined reference to `XMapRaised'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv]+0x74): undefined reference to`XWindowEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv]+0xcb): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv]+0xe9): undefined reference to`XSync'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_paint(bool)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6_paintEb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6_paintEb]+0xcd): undefined reference to`XSendEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6_paintEb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6_paintEb]+0x130): undefined reference to `XPutImage'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_init_fullscreen()':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0xfe): undefined reference to `XCreateWindow'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x1df): undefined reference to`XCreateImage'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x208): undefined reference to `XSelectInput'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x226): undefined reference to`XMapRaised'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x24a): undefined reference to `XWindowEvent'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x2c1): undefined reference to`XPutImage'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x2e6): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x304): undefined reference to`XSync'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_desinit_fullscreen()':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay19_desinit_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay19_desinit_fullscreenEv]+0x28): undefined reference to`XUngrabKeyboard'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay19_desinit_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay19_desinit_fullscreenEv]+0x4d): undefined reference to `XDestroyWindow'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_assign(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int, bool, bool)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0xf7): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x330): undefined reference to`XVisualIDFromVisual'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x34b): undefined reference to `XGetVisualInfo'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x392): undefined reference to`XFree'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x3d2): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x57c): undefined reference to`XCreateWindow'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x5e3): undefined reference to `XCreateSimpleWindow'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x614): undefined reference to`XSelectInput'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x650): undefined reference to `XStoreName'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x6ab): undefined reference to`XCreateColormap'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x703): undefined reference to `XSetWindowColormap'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x70b): undefined reference to`XAllocClassHint'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x741): undefined reference to `XSetClassHint'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x74f): undefined reference to`XFree'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x84a): undefined reference to `XCreateImage'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x870): undefined reference to`XInternAtom'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x896): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x8ce): undefined reference to`XSetWMProtocols'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x902): undefined reference to `XGrabKeyboard'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`cimg_library::CImgDisplay::assign()':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv]+0x10c): undefined reference to `XDestroyWindow'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv]+0x17b): undefined reference to`XFreeColormap'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv]+0x198): undefined reference to `XSync'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function`cimg_library::CImgDisplay::resize(int, int, bool)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib]+0x208): undefined reference to `XResizeWindow'
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib]+0x227): undefined reference to`XGetWindowAttributes'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::move(int, int)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay4moveEii[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay4moveEii]+0x72): undefined reference to`XMoveWindow'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function `void cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_resize<unsigned char>(unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_resizeIhEEvT_jjb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_resizeIhEEvT_jjb]+0x106): undefined reference to`XCreateImage'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function `void cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_resize<unsigned short>(unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_resizeItEEvT_jjb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_resizeItEEvT_jjb]+0x10b): undefined reference to`XCreateImage'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function `void cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_resize<unsigned int>(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_resizeIjEEvT_jjb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_resizeIjEEvT_jjb]+0x106): undefined reference to`XCreateImage'
>   /tmp/ccRIIPim.o: In function `boost::filesystem::path::path<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::path_traits::is_pathable<boost::decay<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>::type>, void>::type*)':
>   grayscaleConvertor.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem4pathC2INS0_15directory_entryEEERKT_PNS_9enable_ifINS0_11path_traits11is_pathableINS_5decayIS4_E4typeEEEvE4typeE[_ZN5boost10filesystem4pathC5INS0_15directory_entryEEERKT_PNS_9enable_ifINS0_11path_traits11is_pathableINS_5decayIS4_E4typeEEEvE4typeE]+0x21): undefined reference to`boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >&)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

grayscaleConvertor.cpp

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED 
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

#include "CImg.h"
#include  <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

namespace fs = ::boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    const string ext = ".png";
    fs::path root("/Downloads/testdata1/");

    if(!fs::exists(root) || !fs::is_directory(root)) return -1;

    fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(root);
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator endit;

    while(it != endit)
    {
        if(fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension()==ext)
        {
            CImg<unsigned char> image(it->path().filename().string().c_str()),
                gray(image.width(), image.height(), 1, 1, 0),
                grayWeight(image.width(), image.height(), 1, 1, 0),
                imgR(image.width(), image.height(), 1, 3, 0),
                imgG(image.width(), image.height(), 1, 3, 0),
                imgB(image.width(), image.height(), 1, 3, 0);
        }
        ++it;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I am using the -l args in the compiler command. eg: -lboost_filesystem which I read on another post in stackoverflow, but that is not helping resolve the boost::filesystem:: symbols

Comment: Somethings not linking, this could happen for a dozen reasons. The answer I would give (if you posted enough info) would not be of interested to a general audience.

Comment: Let me know of any more info you need. I really need this to work.

Comment: `-l` is not sufficient by itself unless the library is in the default search path.  Try adding a `-L` before it to sepcify the directory where the following `-l` libraries can be found.

Comment: locate boost and locate CImg both show /usr/include/ as the locations

Comment: `/usr/include` is where the library headers are located. This is required at compile time. Your issue is at link time, therefore you need to specify where the libraries themselves are located, e.g. something like `-L/path/to/boost/libraries/`

Comment: I used -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ in the command line and still the same behaviour for boost symbols.

ls /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ | grep libboost shows libboost_system.so, libboost_system.so.1.58.0 and libboost_filesystem.so, libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0